# Interpolate class objects

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have a simple `Point` class as follows

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

I would like to use [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) to interpolate these points as a function of time, e.g.

```
x,y,z = f(t)
```

However when I try the following small example

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

times = np.array([0.0, 0.1, 0.2])
points = np.array([Point(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   Point(1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                   Point(2.0, 2.0, 2.0)])

function = interp1d(times, points)

new_point = function(0.05)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/example.py", line 31, in <module>
    function = interp1d(times, points)
  File "C:\long_path\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 439, in __init__
    y = y.astype(np.float_)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Point'
```

I've also tried overloading the arithmetic operators for the `Point` class (e.g. `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__truediv__`) though that doesn't seem to help.

Is there a way I can use `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` with my class?

Comment: Why not put all points in a `Nx3` float64 array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since python object are internally dicts instead of contiguous buffer, numpy/scipy will fail to use certain methods when custom typed objects are inside `numpy.ndarray`.

A simple solution would be putting all `Point` inside one single `ndarray` with built-in type:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as sp_interp
points = np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                   [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                   [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]], dtype='float64')
times = np.linspace(0.,.2, len(points))

fn_interp = sp_interp.interp1d(times, points, axis=0)
print(fn_interp(0.05))
```

If you are dedicated to class based approach, you might want to define custom `dtype` or make subclass of `ndarray`, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350072/custom-data-types-in-numpy-arrays)