# How to convert from a NumPy data type to a custom data type?

Tags: python, numpy

I have defined a new numeric data type in Python using [Python's Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). I would like to convert all my existing NumPy arrays from their existing data types to my custom data type. I understand that NumPy's [astype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) method converts from one data type to another, but based on my understanding, it can only convert between built-in data types.

In contrast to the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350072/custom-data-types-in-numpy-arrays), my data type is not based on built-in data types and has it's own addition, multiplication, bit-wise operations, etc., so I cannot use `np.dtype` to define my data type. In other words, the following solution would not work:

```
kerneldt = np.dtype([('myintname', np.int32), ('myfloats', np.float64, 9)])
arr = np.empty(dims, dtype=kerneldt)
```

Is there any way to convert between a built-in data type and a custom data type and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently possible. There are plans to allow custom dtypes in numpy in the future.