# How can I efficiently sum up the properties of a list of objects in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I have a 2D NumPy array that stores an object called Node, and each Node object has a value; self.c.

```
import numpy

class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 1

size = 10
node_array = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=Node)

for x in range(size):
    for y in range(size):
        node_array[x][y] = Node()
```

I want to efficiently sum up all of the nodes' self.c values in the node_array without having to loop through the node_array. For example:

```
total = 0
for x in range(size):
    for y in range(size):
        total += node_array[x][y].c
```

If the numpy array stored the integer itself instead of the object, I could use np.sum(integer_array) without having to loop through the whole array, which is computationally expensive. For example:

```
integer_array = np.ones((size, size))
sum = np.sum(integer_array)
```

Is there a function or way to do the above with my np array that stores objects instead of integers?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding solutions to this. I think storing objects in a numpy array defeats the purpose of using numpy, it's optimized for storing values.

Comment: You could create a custom dtype for ```Node```, which I think would be the easiest. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350072/custom-data-types-in-numpy-arrays

Comment: An `object` dtype array has about the same "efficiency" as a list.  Functions like `np.sum` will iterate (at python speeds) through the array, delegating the action to the element's `__add__` method (if any).  Your array stores references to your `Node` instances, just as a list does.  That means all access to the `c` attribute has to go through your `Node` code.

Answer (score 3):

`np.sum` seems to work as long as you specify a way for `Node` to be added.

```py
In [18]: class Node:
    ...:     def __init__(self, i):
    ...:         self.c = i
    ...:     def __add__(self, other):
    ...:         if isinstance(other, Node): # Node
    ...:             return self.c + other.c
    ...:         else: # Assume int
    ...:             return self.c + other
    ...:     def __radd__(self, other):
    ...:         return self + other
    ...:     def __repr__(self):
    ...:         return str(self.c)
    ...:

In [19]: arr = np.array([Node(i) for i in range(5)])

In [20]: arr
Out[20]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=object)

In [21]: np.sum(arr)
Out[21]: 10

In [22]: arr = np.array([Node(i) for i in range(100)]).reshape(-1,10)

In [23]: np.sum(arr)
Out[23]: 4950
```

Comment: Your class additions are nice, though I'd add some text to the `repr` (so it doesn't look just like a number).  But it doesn't do anything for efficiency.  `sum(arr.rvel().tolist())` is faster than `np.sum(arr)`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!